# How to debug java stream in visual studio code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Can I use `Debugger for Java` achieve the goal?
Or is there any other plugin can debug stream?

Comment: What exactly do you want to debug about it? It is just a class like any other and you can set breakpoints and interact with it. The only "special" thing is that streams are mostly lazy and do not operate on the data until a terminal operation.

Comment: I want to see the data flow, just like the idea debug tool. @luk2302

Comment: Apparently not.  But your question is off-topic.